# How to insert a blank line above another line

Tags: command-line, line-breaks

I have these lines;

```
Question1. Is this true?
a. Yes
b. No
Question2. How is the weather
a. Good
b. Bad
Question3. The sky is
a. Dark
b. Blue
```

I wanted to change it to;

```
Question1. Is this true?
a. Yes
b. No

Question2. How is the weather
a. Good
b. Bad

Question3. The sky is
a. Dark
b. Blue
```

Is it possible to do this with a one liner command on Vim(version 81)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `:g` command. There are probably already answers here on how to use `:g` and there is also this [famous wiki article on the same topic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

In short, you simply run:

```
:g/^Q/:-put =''
```

which basically means, for each line starting with `Q` put an empty line above it. Alternatively you could use:

```
:g/^b/:pu =''
```

which would add an empty line below each line starting with `b`.

Comment: Nice one! Also possible to use `put! =''` to put before the matched line, which doesn't require the use of `-` to match the line above. And typically I tend to avoid the optional `:` in the middle of a command, like here, I think it might look unclear to some (is that part of how `:g` works?) Though in this case, it might help see that the `-` is an additional address to `:put` rather than part of the pattern given to `:g` (though wouldn't they work the same?)

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on @Christian Brabandt's answer, you can use the `O` key (see `:help O`) and do:

```
:g/^Q/norm O
```

`norm` allows to run a key command (`O`, `dd`, .....) in a command.

`:g` can take a range also, so if you don't want to do it on the first question, you could do:

```
`:2,$g/^Q/norm O
```

Assuming that your file contains only that text, otherwise, the range needs to be adjusted.